# Trouble opening Mainwindow.xib in Xcode/iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I was going through the Hello World tutorial for iPhone App. I recently bought a Macbook and have installed Xcode 3.2.3. The tutorial says that I should double click on MainWindow.xib and wait for few seconds to see an Interface builder getting opened. But nothing like that is happening in my macbook. Is there an alternate way to bring up the Interface builder or even to check whether I have the Interface builder at all!?

http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/3412/problemym.png

Rest of the stuff like iPhone simulator are working properly. What am I doing wrong. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to finder and search for "interface builder" as a file name. see if the application is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything listed on all websites over internet and if nothing works then try this:

Right click on MainWindow.xib -> GetInfo -> General -> "Path: Relative to current SDK"